# How to define exceptions for nx-lint?

Tags: lint, nrwl-nx

I have a readme file which has docs for the folder, the contained libs and how to use them.

The readme is not part of any lib and so nx-lint throws this error:

```
 NX   ERROR  The following file(s) do not belong to any projects:   
    - libs/global/README.md
```

How can we suppress this error?

Notes:

- I don't want to move the file into a lib - the current location is correct
- I don't want to add something to the readme that is visible
- Ideally we only suppress this specific error for this file

I tried to use exclude in the top-level `tslint.json` like this:

```json
{
  "exclude": [
    "libs/global/*.md"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the file `.nxignore` in the project root to fix this:

```
$ yarn lint
yarn run v1.22.4
$ nx workspace-lint && nx lint

>  NX   ERROR  The following file(s) do not belong to any projects:

  - libs/global/README.md

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

$ echo libs/global/README.md >> .nxignore

$ yarn lint
yarn run v1.22.4
$ nx workspace-lint && nx lint

Linting "server"...

All files pass linting.

✨  Done in 2.45s.
```

Comment: @Danziger try to update nx to the newest version - there was an [issue#3453](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/3453) with nxignore that was fixed in `10.0.13`

Comment: @TmTron I was already on the latest version, but my issue was coming from a different place: I had a lib and an app with the same name, so there was a single entry in `workspace.json`. Fixed it by renaming one of them and adding the missing entry.